# Renew Facebook Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm reading a lot of articles that teach how facebook access tokens can be extended, but I can't find any with renewal access token.

I'm using Facebook C# SDK and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient ();

Dictionary<string, object> fbParams = new Dictionary<string, object> ();

fbParams["client_id"]         = token.appId;
fbParams["grant_type"]        = "fb_exchange_token";
fbParams["client_secret"]     = token.appSecret;
fbParams["fb_exchange_token"] = token.accessToken;

JsonObject publishedResponse = fbClient.Get ("/oauth/access_token", fbParams) as JsonObject;
return publishedResponse["access_token"].ToString ();
```

But is seems to work only to extend a token, when I use it with an expired one it returns me the following message:

Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1365165211. The current unix time is 1382106470.

Does anyone know how can I handle this? How can I renew my session? I'm making this project as a console application in VS2012.

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

I found this code:

```
fbParams["client_id"]         = token.appId;
fbParams["grant_type"]        = "client_credentials";
fbParams["client_secret"]     = token.appSecret;
fbParams["fb_exchange_token"] = token.accessToken;
```

It returns an access token, but when I use it:

"No user access token specified"

But it is specified Oo

Comment: Vote up because of the Oo emoticon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot renew token with any expired access_token you required valid access token when you request for `fb_exchange_token`